# How to relay NAT dynamic port numbers if the server receives 0 as port no?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, udp, httprequest

I'm trying to implement udp punch holing through a Java servlet. However when I use req.getRemotePort() I always get 0 (i.e. dynamic). That's doesn't help. Any way around that? Alternative solutions?

http://sss.mysimpatico.com/server?authentication=unregistered

The code that prints the first 0 and the one attached to the ip:

```
final int port = req.getRemotePort();
pw.println(port);
final String ip = req.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + port;
```

There is a GAE issue (please star it if you are interested):
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4210

Comment: Assuming you are talking about HttpServletRequest.getRemotePort(), I don't see how it can possibly return zero. It has to return the outbound port of the connected client, which can't be zero. You would have to tell us a lot more about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as google-app-engine; Google App Engine uses HTTP (see the [sandbox](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) section), [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) uses TCP not UDP.

Comment: i knew http used tcp. So? 
The sandbox only mentions: "Other computers can only connect to the application by making HTTP (or HTTPS) requests on the standard ports.", i.e. 80. That's the port on the server-end. The client may connect from any port.

Comment: So what does UDP have to do with it? and what's the relevance of the part after 'So?'?

Comment: UDP is the communication wanted btw the 2 clients. Does the communication with the server need to be through TCP too, then? The part after so expands the reference to the sandbox

Comment: Both the request and the response are HTTP, so yes -- the response will also be TCP.

Comment: sorry, what I meant was the communication between the clients. Does the communication between the clients need to be TCP too, since it's so with the server? My assumption is no. So considering that http uses tcp is irrelevant.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with App Engine, then?

Comment: Yes, the server is hosted on gae. So if gae does something special (such as the things described in sandbox) that's not in servlet spec that might be the reason. I.e. if you ran the same servlet code on a tomcat webserver, do you also get 0?

Comment: So, again, what does UDP have to do with this problem? You claim you're getting 0 from HttpServletRequest.getRemotePort(). That's an HTTP over TCP transaction.

Comment: nothing! It's the purpose of these communications with the server.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a gae problem since the same code returns > 0 ports: http://pschmidt.dyndns-server.com/Server (temporary)